# Join not fetching data correctlly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a procedure like below lines of code.

```
SELECT CountryID,
CountryName, 
CountryCode,
Longitude,
Latitude,
CreatedBy,
CreatedOn,
UpdatedOn,
UpdatedBy
FROM Country AS C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
            FROM    Cause CS
            WHERE   CS.CountryName like C.CountryName
        )
```

Basically there are two tables `Country` with `CountryID` and `CountryName` fields and `Cause` with three fields: `CauseId`, `CauseName` and `CountryName`.

I am trying to fetch all countries which are assigned to cause. The above code is not working.

Comment: remove TOP 1 1 put TOP 1

Comment: First, remove the `TOP 1` entirely.  It does nothing in an `EXISTS` query.  Second, please explain what "not working" means.  Do you get an error?  If so, what error.  Does the query not return what you expect?  If so, please provide sample data and your desired results.  Third, if you have a `CountryId` column, why does the foreign key reference use the name instead of the id?

Comment: How question title is related to question? There is no `inner join` in your query.

Comment: Third, this is not actually a join, but it could probably be done as one. Why is there a `LIKE` operator between the CountryName fields?

Comment: It doesn't display any country despite there are many countries assigned to the cause. It still display no records

Comment: @Nida post some sampling data.

Comment: Check if data in `CS.CountryName` and `C.CountryName` is exactly same. if not you can use `LTRIM(RTIM(CS.CountryName)) like '%'+ LTRIM(RTRIM(C.CountryName)) + '%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Country c 
Inner join Cause cs on cs.CountryName = c.CountryName
```

This will get you all the countries that have causes. Hope i understood what you wanted.

This works if the cs.CountryName is identical to c.CountryName. Also mind the fact that an EXISTS takes much longer then an join and also consider indexing the CountryName column